# ReactDOM vs Fancy Routing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

While learning React, I'm building a small demo app and I really don't need semantic routing to be visible in the URL. This is an internal admin type application that I'm putting together. It might even get wrapped up in electron at some point. Is it feasible to then simply use `ReactDOM.render()` to load page level components and programmatically update the history? What gotcha's might I encounter?

If the above is too broad, then the simpler version is that I want to do this...

```
class Nav extends React.Component {

  navToThing() {
     const container = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
     // This doesn't work
     ReactDOM.render(<Thing />, container);
     // what is the right way to do this?
  }

  render() {
    return <div><a href="#" onClick={this.navToThing}>Nav To Thing</a></div>
  }

}
```